# TypeScript fails to infer type correctly when type alias used

Tags: typescript, typescript-generics

In the code below I have two instances of a `Record<string, string[]>`: one that declares itself directly as the `Record`, and one that uses a type alias referring to the exact same `Record` type. When passing these into a function, along with an empty array (which I expect TypeScript to infer as being an empty string array), TypeScript compiles the first, but not the second. So it looks like the type alias is causing it to have a problem. Is there a way around this? Is this a bug in TypeScript that should be reported?

```
function foo<T>(record: Record<string, T>, entity: T) {
}

type StringArrayRecord = Record<string, string[]>;

function test() {
    const working: Record<string, string[]> = {};
    foo(working, []); // Compiles

    const broken: StringArrayRecord = {};
    foo(broken, []); // Does not compile
}
```

The error is:

```
Argument of type 'StringArrayRecord' is not assignable to parameter of type 'Record<string, never[]>'.
  'string' index signatures are incompatible.
    Type 'string[]' is not assignable to type 'never[]'.
      Type 'string' is not assignable to type 'never'.
```

If I try a different type instead of `string[]` as the second type parameter in the record, I get the same problem as soon as there is any ambiguity in the type (e.g. if it's a union type), e.g.

```
type StringOrNumberRecord = Record<string, string | number>;

function test() {
    const working: Record<string, string | number> = {};
    foo(working, "string"); // Compiles

    const broken: StringOrNumberRecord = {};
    foo(broken, "string"); // Does not compile
}
```

(Am getting this both with TypeScript 4.8 and with 5.)

(One possible solution is to explicitly tell the compiler the type of the second parameter when calling `foo`, e.g. `foo(broken, "string" as string | number);`. Another is specify the generic type parameter when calling `foo`, e.g. `foo<string | number>(broken, "string")`. But both of these seem like they should not be necessary.)

Comment: What is your tsconfig.json config as I try to compile it and it does not fail?

Comment: Just the default when using `npx tsc --init`

Comment: This seems like an unfortunate interaction in the generic inference algorithm; one wouldn't think that using a type alias would lower the priority of an inference site, but I guess it does.  I couldn't find an obviously relevant issue in GitHub about this.  Someone might want to file one and then report back here with an official answer once it gets triaged.

Comment: Thanks @jcalz. Have now logged this as an issue: https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/54000.

Comment: Okay, that got triaged. Do you want to write up your own answer here or shall I do it?

Comment: I feel you have a much greater understanding of the compiler so could explain it much better than I could :-) So why don't you write it up (assuming you're happy to?) and I'll then mark it as the correct answer.

Comment: you can do `function foo<T extends Record<string, unknown[]>>(record: T, entity: T[string]) {}` and coerce TS to determine `T` from the `Record` and match the arrays type against that. Not determine `T` from the (empty) array and try to match the Records values against that type.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is apparently working as intended, according to [microsoft/TypeScript#54000](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/54000) although it's definitely strange when a type alias has such a large effect on inference.

The reason for the difference is that when TypeScript compares two types, it often has to recursively match up pieces of each one before deciding if they are the same, or different, or if one can be used to infer pieces of the other.

But if they both types are written in terms of an identical [generic](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/generics.html) type with known *variance* in its type parameter (see [Difference between Variance, Covariance, Contravariance, Bivariance and Invariance in TypeScript](https://stackoverflow.com/q/66410115/2887218) ), then the compiler can take a shortcut by just comparing the type arguments.  For example, if the compiler is comparing `F<string>` to `F<unknown>` for the following `F<T>` type

```
type F<T> = {
  prop: T;
  otherProp: string;
  anotherProp: number;
  // ... lots more stuff, none of which depend on T
}
```

which it has already analyzed as being *covariant* in its type parameter, then it can immediately say that `F<string>` is a subtype of `F<unknown>` because `string` is a subtype of `unknown`, without needing to actually *evaluate* `F<string>` or `F<unknown>` and compare them directly.

This shortcut is, to a first approximation, just a faster way of getting the same result it would have gotten the long slow way.

---

On the other hand, if the compiler is comparing `F<string>` to `G` for the following `G` type

```
type G = F<unknown>
```

then it would need to start evaluating the types before it could compare them.  If it does so by plugging `string` into `F` and then evaluating `G`, it would be too late to notice that they are both in terms of `F` and therefore it needs to start comparing all the properties of both.

This will eventually determine that `F<string>` is a subtype of `G`.  But it does so through a different path.

(And you can substitute `Record<string, T>` for `F<T>` and `Record<string, string[]>` for `G` if you want here.)

---

Even though these have basically the same result, there are observable differences, for better or worse.  And one is that it can affect generic type argument inference.

When inferring `Record<string, T>` from a value of type `Record<string, string[]>` at the same time as inferring `T` from a value of type `never[]` (which is the default type of an empty array), the compiler can immediately use the variance marker on `Record`'s second type parameter to see that as the same as inferring `T` from `string[]` and `T` from `never[]`.  These two inference candidates are given equal priority and the compiler decides that `string[]` is the right choice because `never[]` is assignable to `string[]`.

On the other hand when inferring `Record<string, T>` from a value of type `StringOrNumberRecord` at the same time as inferring `T` from a value of type `never[]`, the compiler cannot take the shortcut of variance markings.  It needs to evaluate `StringOrNumberRecord` to do that, and therefore the inference candidate of `never[]` has a higher priority because it's more direct.  And then when it does finally evaluate `StringOrNumberRecord` it fails because it's not assignable to `Record<string, never[]>`.

It's an unfortunate inconsistency in behavior, but neither way is "incorrect" per se.  And according to [the TS team dev lead](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/54000#issuecomment-1520867782), the more consistent fix would be to lower the variance marker priority and have *both* calls fail, which probably wouldn't make anyone happier.  So it is what it is, at least for now.

Answer (score 0):

The main issue is that you didn't specify the type of `T` in `foo` when you call it:

```
// Here T is a generic type
function foo<T>(record: Record<string, T>, entity: T) {
}

// broken is of type Record<string, string[]>
const broken: StringArrayRecord = {};

foo(broken, []); // Does not compile since the type of [] is uknown[]
```

See the issue there? You have  value of the second parameter passed as `[]` which for Typescript its an empty untyped array so it resolves into `uknown[]` thus the mismatch.

If you put an empty string there like:

```
foo(broken, [""]);
```

Now the compiler can infer the parameters as `string[]` which is valid and resolved without issues.

Comment: Thanks, but I don't think this really answers the question. The suggestion you provide is similar to what I list as possible solutions at the bottom of my question. But the question is: why do I need to do these workarounds _only if using the type alias_? (Also, FYI, I can't use `[""]` as that's not an empty array: I'd need to do, for example, `[] as string[]`, or `foo<string[]>(broken, [])`.)

Comment: Because you are not specifying the type of `T` when you pass `foo(broken, []);` since 
`[]` resolves into `unknown[]` which makes sense. You could have added anything there in the list so the compiler needs to have more information about the type you are using for `T`.

Hense when using `[] as string[]` or `foo<string[]>(broken, [])` the compiler can infer the type  of `T` as `string[]`.

Comment: I totally get what you're saying, but that's not my question. My question is: why is it only necessary to specify `T` when using the type alias? Why does this work: `foo(working, []);`, but this doesn't: `foo(broken, []);`? Both are exactly the same, it's just that the latter uses a type alias for the `Record`.